# What is the purpose of using a true random number for an NFT?

Tags: nft, chainlink, randomness

I don't understand what the purpose of using [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/) for my NFT's generation is.

Why don't I just launch and pick the NFT traits myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common problem in the traditional web2 art and trading card world is the transparency of randomness and scarcity.

If you buy a trading card, like a Pokémon card for example, you have no way of knowing how rare it really is without talking to the company that printed it. There is a centralized component to the scarcity of the card. They could have printed millions of the card, making it worthless, or just 1, making it incredibly rare.

With NFTs, if you are the one who can control how rare a card is, you are a centralized component of rarity, and not a decentralized component.

Now, if you use Chainlink VRF to mint your cards, you have 0 control of how rare the card is, and you can rely on true randomness. This gives uses of the NFTs a proven way to know how rare and how scarce your NFTs are, making them more valuable and tamper-proof.

This solves the centralized issue of diluting the value of NFTs by printing more "rare" ones, giving them actual value.